# How to map Json attributes to the mongo db fields

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, underscore.js

I am parsing the Excel file into json using [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) npm module and I am getting the json result like this -

```
[
  {
    "Arriving Date": "05/13/16",
    "License NO": "xxxxxx",
    "Lab Name": "ABC",
    "Type ": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "Arriving Date": "05/13/16",
    "License NO": "ttttt",
    "Lab Name": "SDF",
    "Type ": "vvv"
  }
]
```

and I want to insert the json array of objects into the mongo-db.I am doing that by this code -

```
Data.collection.insert(data, onInsert);

    function onInsert(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            totalinserted = docs.length;
            console.info('%d Products were successfully stored.', docs.length);
        }
        //res.send({message: totalinserted + " " + 'successfully stored '})
    }
```

But in my mongodb model all fields are defined like this'

```
{
arrivingdate:Date,
licenseno:Number,
labname:String,
type:String
}
```

here I want to map each field of json to the Perticular field of mongodb can anybody help me on this?

Comment: can any one help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var output = []
var input = [
  {
    "Arriving Date": "05/13/16",
    "License NO": "xxxxxx",
    "Lab Name": "ABC",
    "Type ": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "Arriving Date": "05/13/16",
    "License NO": "ttttt",
    "Lab Name": "SDF",
    "Type ": "vvv"
  }
];
input.forEach(function(item){
    var converted = {}
    for(var k in item){
        converted[k.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")] = item[k]
        if(newkey == 'arrivingdate'){
            converted[newkey] = new Date(item[k].split("/"))
        }
        if(newkey == 'licenseno'){
           converted[newkey] = parseInt(item[k])
        }
    }
    output.push(converted)
})
console.log(output);
```